# Return part of image as an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

How can I do the following with Jquery?

If you don't have any examples or code, please just outline the process for me!

1) **Get a (x,y coordinate) square of an image from url.**

2) **Return that image as an image object.**

3) **Echo that image on my page as if its a direct url to the image?**

So, image is hosted on site **A** and i want to "echo" a portion of the image on site **B** as an image itself.

The images i'm cropping all have the same size, i will need a 64 x 64 crop from the base coords (0,0). The goal of this is to get a distinct url of the cropped image.

Comment: let's back up four steps (that's not a miscount). What are you actually trying to do, rather than what you think the steps are to get that done?

Comment: Echo parts of an image on my webpage, as an image themselves.

Comment: This is for an API im writing that my application needs.

Comment: Why don't you just use background-size and background-position in CSS? 

Otherwise there are many jQuery Plugins for image processing: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=resize%20and%20crop%20image%20jquery#q=resize+and+crop+image+jquery

Comment: I want to seperate the section-image from the parent image. So when you visit the page with this jquery function, you could download the image (which would be the section from the parent). sorry if this is confusing

Comment: @user2816960 that's not an anwser. Can you describe what you want to do rather than describing the steps you think are needed for that? For instance: "I want to implement something that lets me give it an image URL, and a cropping box, and then have that serve up the cropped image as a distinct url". Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry for not answering, yes that is exactly what i want to make, except no cropping box (just set coordinates). The goal of this is to get a distinct url of the cropped image.

Comment: then what's the point of the coordinate? How can you not want the cropping box, but do want a cropped image? (note: just because you pass two coordinates, doesn't mean you don't end up with a cropping box x/y/w-x/h-y)

Comment: the images im cropping all have the same size, i just need 64 x 64 crop from the coords (0,0). I just assumed coordinates were needed even if they're always the same.

Comment: Wow, now we're talking details: want to add all that information to your actual question? We have no way of guessing that all your images are the same size and you already know the cropping box, for instance.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well thats what you're here for! to remind me to do so! ill add those details

Comment: It really isn't. We're here to help you, based on your detailed and complete question. Before posting one, always ask yourself "if I asked a random stranger this, how many counter questions can I expect" and resolve all of those before posting. Going back and forth in the comments for more details is actually wasting the time of potential helpers.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans okay, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to link directly to image and "crop" desired part with css `clip` property.

Comment: this doesn't modify the image at all, only clips for viewing

Comment: why would that be a problem? If your end goal is a clipped image, this answer is pretty good.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the goal is a direct url, with a cropped image. this just changes how it looks on the page, doesn't actually crop the image.

Comment: if you drag a CSS clipped image off the page its on, you'll get the entire image. I want to be able to drag it off the page, and get the cropped image.

Comment: Other option is to request image with JS, crop it with canvas and then retern as base64 url.

Comment: you just keep inventing more details... why does dragging it of the page matter? By god man, can you just please give us all the information up front =P That said @Bodzio suggestion will work without any need for a PHP looparound. Just draw the image to a crop canvas, and get a new image out with `toDataURL("image/png")` or the like

Comment: My application needs to show the image from the direct url. So if its clipped that does nothing, because the image file at the url needs to be cropped. I thought that was understood after all the questions above. Ill try the JS option thanks for your time.